# How to remove the output characters ;# via xsl? (SharePoint ItemStyle.xsl)

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I am editing the SharePoint 2016 ItemStyle.xsl file as I am feeding data from a custom list into a Content Query webpart. It's working well however the checkbox output is adding ;# around each selected checkbox item. I was wondering if there was somethig I could add to the xsl that removes this?
The code I'm using is:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Position" />
```

The output is:
;#Manager;#

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@Position,';#', '')"/>
```

However this would also remove any legitimate `;` and `#` characters within the data. So it might be preferable to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@Position, 3, string-length(@Position) - 4)"/>
```

---

This is assuming you're using XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 2.0 you could use regex as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(@Position, '^;#|;#$', '')"/>
```

to remove only the starting and ending `;#` substrings.

---

In either case I don't see why you need `disable-output-escaping`.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function as

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="replace(@Position, ';#', '')" />
```